# Adding back button and gesture to TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I've started recently my debut in swift, so I still can't get the hang of it.

I am trying to make a ViewController to display some results, a list of element each having 2 string and a image. Thus I've gotten to the following code:

```
@objc class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var tableList = [cellData]()
    var viewImages = false
    var advancedMode = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.allowsSelection = false
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func goBack(){
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableList.count;
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch tableList[indexPath.row].cell {
        case 2:
            let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell2", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell2
            cell.Header.text = tableList[indexPath.row].header
            cell.Details.text = tableList[indexPath.row].details
            cell._Image.image = tableList[indexPath.row]._image

            return cell

        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
            return cell

        }

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        switch tableList[indexPath.row].cell {
        case 1:
            return 127.0;
        case 2:
            return 50 +
                ((tableList[indexPath.row].details != nil && tableList[indexPath.row].details.count > 0) ? 100 : 0) +
                (tableList[indexPath.row]._image != nil && tableList[indexPath.row]._image.size.height > 0
                    ? ((tableList[indexPath.row]._image.size.width/self.view.frame.size.width) *  tableList[indexPath.row]._image.size.height)
                    : 0);  // TODO: here we should get the proper height from the image based on the with of the view
        default:
            return 50.0;
        }
    }

    @objc
    func clearTable() ->Void {
        tableList.removeAll()
    }

    @objc
    func addElement(header: String, details: String, image:UIImage) -> Void{
        tableList.append(cellData(cell: 2, header: header, details: details, _image: image))
    }


}
```

This codes works great by listing the results. But I want to add the back feature.

- I've tried to embed the first controller with navigation control, but for the tableViewController there was no header with back button. Not in the storyboard or when running the program.
- I've tried to use this by setting the background red and adding a UIButton, but there was no button. Yet there was a red zone that appeared when running the program

  ```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? { ..  }
  ```
- I've tried to replace the button with the back swipe gesture, but there was no reaction there either

Any ideas where I might have made a mistake or what I am missing?

**Update 1**:
In the previous view controller I used the following code to go to the TableViewController:

```
TableViewController *vc = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I needed to jump to TableViewController when a certain process/condition was done (so not by pressing a button)

Comment: Where would the back button take you?

Comment: Check your segue type. It should be `show`. If the segue is `modal` there will be no back button.

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan, it is possible to be something related to this, I am still new to ios, could you please share an example

Comment: I've edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the Storyboard. When you create a segue by control dragging to another view controller and letting the mouse a small menu should appear like this:

[image]

Under the `Action Segue` section there are segue types. For your case, you need to select `Show`. Now, if you embed the first view controller in a navigation controller, a back button will appear on the second one.

This will also work if your first view controller is already embedded in a navigation controller and you create a `Show` segue from it to another one.

For checking your segue's kind, just tap on its arrow and in the utilities area (the right panel) you can see its kind under `Kind` section.

**EDIT**

If you are using Objective-C and do segueing programatically, here is the way: 
Each view controller has a property called `navigationController`, which holds a reference to the navigation controller in which it is embedded. If your view controller is already embedded in a navigation controller here is how you can do your transition:

```
 - (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
ViewController2 *viewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc ] init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController: viewController2 animated:YES];
```

}

P.s. You can check Stanford's course for iOS development: CS193P. It is free.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the tip with CS193P. There is no Segue in the Storyboard (not even when I embed the Navigation Controller in the root), I am just using the code mentioned int he Update1 to go to the TableViewController.  I'll look into it to see how to add one. Still, if I don't use the Segue, is there no other way around it?

Comment: I've just noticed your **EDIT**, indeed it was both that I had to add a navigation controller and change to pushViewController. Many thanks. Ps. good videos :D

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Could you accept the answer so others know that it works?:)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the left bar button as:

```
let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "imagename"), style: .plain, target: 
self, action: Selector("action")) // action:#selector(Class.MethodName) for swift 3
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = button1
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've just tried this, but still no navigation bar or button appeared, only the table was displayed

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after I watched some videos on CS193P (thank you @Tigran Iskandaryan) and played in another project, I've found the solution.

So, the problem was: 
`[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];`

From what I've read, in order for NavigationController to work as should, it needs the ViewControllers to be stacked. And because I used a diffrent way to jump to the next ViewController, it didn't need to display the navigation bar.

So, the fix was to use `pushViewController` instead of `presentViewController`. That way, the ViewController will be stacked within the NavigationBar.

Thus, it will be:

```
TableViewController *vc = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Note, that in order for it to work I had to make sure to embed the nMvigationController into the root ViewController